# Convert UTC to Eastern timezone

Tags: c#, timezone

I have a UTC timestamp coming in UTC (string type). I want this timestamp to be converted to Eastern Time. The problem is when i call DateTime.Parse or Convert.ToDateTime on the UTC timestamp, it is converting it to my local time, which is Central Time.

How can I take a string timestamp and convert it to Eastern Time regardless of the local time of the server its running on?

Comment: I am not sure but you can try with Cultures. Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: @George - Cultures have nothing to do with time zones.  They don't affect them one bit.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I will try to dissect your question, but next time please show some code so everyone can see exactly what you mean more clearly.

> I have a UTC timestamp coming in UTC (string type).

Ok, I assume you mean something like this:

```
string utcString = "2014-02-25T12:34:56.000Z";
```

This is an [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) UTC timestamp.  If it's in some other format, let me know in comments and I will update the answer accordingly.

> ... The problem is when I call `DateTime.Parse` or `Convert.ToDateTime` on the UTC timestamp, it is converting it to my local time, which is Central Time.

```
DateTime utcDateTime = DateTime.Parse(utcString,
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                      DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
```

The `RoundtripKind` style tells the parser to look for "kind" information in the input string, such as the `Z` that indicates UTC. The resulting `DateTime` will have the original value, and it's `.Kind` property set to `DateTimeKind.Utc`.

> ... I want this timestamp to be converted to Eastern Time.

Now that you have  a UTC `DateTime`, you can convert it easily using the `TimeZoneInfo` class.

```
TimeZoneInfo easternTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(
                                                         "Eastern Standard Time");

DateTime easternDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDateTime,
                                                           easternTimeZone);
```

That's it.  The result is a `DateTime` containing the local time in the US Eastern time zone.  It's kind will be `Unspecified`, as the time zone information is not carried along with the `DateTime` object.

Also note that "Eastern Standard Time" refers to the entire US Eastern time zone, inclusive of both EST and EDT.

Comment: You dissected my poorly written question beautifully. Thank you sir.

Comment: what about daylight saving ? sorry if amateur question

Comment: @donstack - No problem.  The above examples already account for daylight saving time.  The Windows time zone ID of `"Eastern Standard Time"` is poorly named, should just be `"Eastern Time"`.  It encompasses both EST and EDT.  See [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) for more examples.

Comment: its incredible that microsoft cant even name their timezones right, making it a nightmare to do it correctly for DST. its not just named poorly. its named INCORRECTLY!

Comment: Quick note about getting a previously stored value to the correct UTC "kind," working from model to view: You can use .ToUniversalTime() (DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()) without first needing to parse the string.

Comment: @CodeBreaker - Yes, but with the caveat that if the existing value in your model has its kind as `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, then the `ToUniversalTime` function will presume that the value is in terms of the local system time.  That can be problematic if, for example, you are developing in Pacific time and your servers are set to UTC.  A better approach is to use the conversion methods on the `TimeZoneInfo` class, specifying a specific source time zone.  Of course, YMMV depending on the nature of the application.

Answer (score 2):

[Take a look here at the documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382770%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Basically you need to use `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("<Timezone>");`
Then use that as the 3rd parameter for the `ConvertTime` function. Parameter 2 being your current timezone.

```
DateTime hwTime = new DateTime(2007, 02, 01, 08, 00, 00);
try
{
   TimeZoneInfo hwZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Hawaiian Standard Time");
   Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} is {2} local time.", 
           hwTime, 
           hwZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(hwTime) ? hwZone.DaylightName : hwZone.StandardName, 
       TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(hwTime, hwZone, TimeZoneInfo.Local));
}
catch (TimeZoneNotFoundException)
{
   Console.WriteLine("The registry does not define the Hawaiian Standard Time zone.");
}                           
catch (InvalidTimeZoneException)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Registry data on the Hawaiian STandard Time zone has been corrupted.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a convenient solution:

```
var e_europe = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("E. Europe Standard Time");
var utcnow = DateTime.UtcNow;
Console.WriteLine(utcnow.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcnow, e_europe).ToString());
```

it prints

```
2/26/2014 1:03:43 AM
2/26/2014 3:03:43 AM
```